# at our side / on our side / from our side

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality

I'm developing a web form wich communicates with an external service and they are validating the data that I send to them from the web form. But, I would like to manage the validation by my self.

I'm a bit of confused about these options, they are very similar:

1. I would like to manage the form validation **on our side**
2. I would like to manage the form validation **at our side**
3. I would like to manage the form validation **from our side**

Do they express the same?

Comment: **At** implies a physical location. E.g. _I would like to manage the form validation at my office_. I don't have a good reason for this (which is why this is a comment), but to me, _on our side_ sounds more natural than _from our side_ in this context.

Comment: @rosslh in what context "from our side" sounds more natural to you? Thanks!

Comment: If your web form or external service uses special rules, please explain; otherwise, may we stick to normal English? Your “form validation” is not relevant. “On our side” clearly suggests that you stand together politically; it matters not where you stand literally, geographically.  
“At our side” is pretty-much diametrically opposite. It clearly suggests that you stand next to each other literally; geographically. It matters not where you stand, politically.
“From our side” has no meaning in and of itself; it depends entirely on context.